# Problem calculating sum of convergent series of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was solving an exercise where I had to show that some series were convergent and then show that their result is the value in front of the equal sign.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}-1} = \frac{3}{4}$$

Proving it's convergent I did the following way

By "moving" the n to 1,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}-2n}$,
then applying the comparison criterion, since ${n^{2}+2n} \ge n^2$ for any n bigger or equal to 1 then $\frac{1}{n^{2}+2n} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$ for any n bigger or equal to 1. Since $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is a convergent p series(n's  exponent is bigger than one) then $\frac{1}{n^2+2n}$ is convergent too.

Now I'm unable to calculte its result. Any tip or solving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**
$$\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: >.< This looks so familiar still I can't make out the path to follow. Could you please give me another hint?

Comment: @krystalgamer Are you familiar with the concept of a telescoping sum?

Comment: Sure, that was actually my first approach. In order to be a telescoping sum the second denominator according to my math needed to be just $n$. Probably the expression needed to be "worked" a little more to like a telescoping sum?

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved it by adding an extra $\frac{1}{n}$ and then solving by doing 2 telescoping sums. Here's the expansion if anyone in the future needs it: $\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}]$

Answer (score 1):

You can get
the partial sums explicitly,
and this will give you
the sum in the limit.

This is also a good example
of working with sums.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1}{n^{2}-1}
&=\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1}{(n+1)(n-1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac12(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n+1})\\
&=\frac12(\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac1{n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^{m}\frac1{n+1})\\
&=\frac12(\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac1{n}-\sum_{n=3}^{m+1}\frac1{n})\\
&=\frac12(1+\frac12+\sum_{n=3}^{m-1} \frac1{n}-(\sum_{n=3}^{m-1}\frac1{n}+\frac1{m}+\frac1{m+1}))
\qquad\text{separate the terms common to both sums}\\
&=\frac12(1+\frac12-\frac1{m}-\frac1{m+1}))
\qquad\text{and here they have cancelled}\\
&=\frac34-\frac12\frac{2m+1}{m(m+1)}
\qquad\text{from here on it is just algebra}\\
&=\frac34-\frac12\frac{2m+2-1}{m(m+1)}\\
&=\frac34-\frac12(\frac{2m+2}{m(m+1)}-\frac{1}{m(m+1)})\\
&=\frac34-\frac12(\frac{2}{m}-\frac{1}{m(m+1)})\\
&=\frac34-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2m(m+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\frac34-\frac{1}{m}
\lt \sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1}{n^{2}-1}
\lt \frac34
$.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! Having multiple ways to solve an exercise is always useful :)