# Find $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Clearly, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-1}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)} \lt \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ which is a convergent p-series, so the original series is convergent as well. But, I don't know how to proceed further and actually find the sum of this series. I took an introductory real analysis course which mostly dealt with finding if a sequence or series is convergent or not, not finding the sum itself. So, I'd really appreciate any help with this, as well as references to any study material from which I could learn more about this topic.

Comment: Apply partial fraction decomposition to the summand and see that the series telescopes.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2580185/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/993890/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E2-1%7D%24)

Comment: *Hint*: $\dfrac{1}{n^2 - 1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{n - 1} - \dfrac{1}{n + 1}\right)$